# How to exclude -1 from the array and stop the program?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Write a program that always asks the user to enter a number. When the user enters -1, the program should stop requesting the user to enter a number. The program must then calculate the average of the numbers entered,excluding the -1.

Make use of the while loop repetition structure to implement the program.

```
let Num = 0;
let array = []



  while(Num != -1) {
   
  let Num = prompt("Enter a number, enter -1 to stop");
  onlyNum = Number(Num);   
  array.push(onlyNum);
  
  console.log(array);

  if(Num == -1) //How to exclude -1 from the array?
   
  console.log("The average is " + array.reduce((a,b)=> a + b, 0) / array.length) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions that accepts positive numbers or 0, and calculates the average once a negative number or non-number text is entered:

```
let array = [];
let num = 0;
while(num >= 0) {
    num = Number(prompt('Enter a number, enter -1 to stop'));
    if(num >= 0) {
        array.push(num);
    } else {
        console.log('The average is ' + array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / array.length);
    }
}
```

More concise:

```
let array = [];
while (true) {
    let num = Number(prompt("Enter a number, enter -1 to stop"));
    if(num < 0 || isNaN(num)) {
        break;
    }
    array.push(num);
}
console.log('The average is ' + array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / array.length);
```